# OCaml : Infinite Loop

Tags: while-loop, ocaml, infinite-scroll

I am trying to do this simple while loop but it's not working. The compiler is not giving any type of error or warning but when i try to run my function it ends up in an infinite loop:

```
let example x =
  let k = ref x in 
  while (!k > 42) do
    if ( (!k mod 5) == 0) then (
      k:= !k/2
    );
  done;
 if(!k<42) then (
   Printf.printf "k is less than 42"  
  );
  if(!k == 42) then (
    Printf.printf "k is equal to 42" 
  )
;;
```

Comment: k = 43, then..?

Comment: @user2864740 Sorry i just added the rest of the code i just wanted to simplify

Comment: Following the logic of your code, while `k` is greater than 42, `k` gets updated only if it's a multiple of 5. There would seem to be _many_ cases where `k` never gets updated in the loop. EDIT: I see Jeffrey Scofield's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your loop only modifies `!k` when `!k mod 5 = 0`. If `!k` isn't divisible by 5, it will never change in value. This suggests that the loop will either run 0 times or will run an infinite number of times.

You don't show any calls to `example`, but any call where you pass a value > 42 and not a multiple of 5 should loop infinitely it seems to me.

By the way, this is what @user2864740 was trying to point out. 43 is  a value > 42 that's not divisible by 5.

(As a side comment, you should use `=` to compare values for equality. The `==` operator in OCaml is useful in limited cases. This often causes problems for people coming from other languages.)

Comment: There are a number of other style issues with this code. Reading [the OCaml programming guidelines](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/guidelines.html) would be very helpful. In particular, about use of parentheses and space around operators.